# How to electron app start with yarn berry?

Tags: electron, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

After moving the code that was running well in the standalone repo to the monorepo, it is not working properly.
As shown in the screen below, the message compiled successfully appears and stopped the message last.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoRcS.png)

If it is executed normally, the logger message in main.ts that should appear is not visible.
If the below is really executed normally, more messages should appear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5g8R.png)

And the following error window appears as if to confirm that an error occurred in main process again.

Error message is here.

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main processUncaught Exception:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The “path” argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
at Object.normalize (node:path:1128:5)
at contains (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:32828:18)
at Object.ppath.contains (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:32842:32)
at isPathIgnored (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:41344:27)
at findPackageLocator (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:41414:9)
at Object.findPackageLocator (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:41706:14)
at findApiPathFor (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:41797:41)
at Object.getApiPathFromParent (/Users/chai/Codes/apple/.pnp.cjs:41848:36)
```

I know that a type error occurred because the path argument that should be entered as a string entered undefined, but I cannot identify the exact location of the error.
However, considering that .pnp.cjs is a 'map' for the dependency and installation location of yarn packages, it can be assumed that there is something wrong with the package installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar and the issue was that electron was not loading my .pnp.cjs.  To fix this, I add the following environment variable to my start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--require path/to/.pnp.cjs' electron ."
}
```